# Oracle UPDATE has no effect

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-update

I am working on Sql Developper an I created the following procedure in a package:

```
PROCEDURE VALIDER(a_session IN NUMBER) AS

i NUMBER;
TYPE type_tab IS TABLE OF PANIER%ROWTYPE;
tabSeances type_tab;

BEGIN
SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO tabSeances
FROM PANIER
WHERE a_session = sessionweb;

i:=0;
FOR i IN 1 .. tabSeances.count LOOP
  -- UPADTE DU NOMBRE DE PLACES LIBRES
  BEGIN
    UPDATE PROJECTION
    SET remaining_seats = (remaining_seats - tabseances(i).nbrplaces)
    WHERE  num_copy = tabseances(i).num_copy 
      AND day = tabseances(i).dateseance
      AND time_slot = tabseances(i).time_slot 
      AND movie = tabseances(i).movie;
    COMMIT;

    --UPDATE ON PANIER
    UPDATE PANIER
    SET valide = 1
    WHERE sessionweb = a_session 
      AND num_copy = tabseances(i).num_copy 
      AND dateseance = tabseances(i).dateseance
      AND time_slot = tabseances(i).time_slot 
      AND movie = tabseances(i).movie;  
    COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION  
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN raise_application_error(-20035, 'Pas de données');
      WHEN OTHERS THEN raise_application_error(-20006,'Autres Erreurs');
  END;
END LOOP; 
END VALIDER;
```

The procedure executes normaly and I don't get an error.

I have a kind of product cart: "PANIER". I loop all the entries in thsi cart for one person (session) to validate them in the database and decrement the total number of seats.

But the field "remaining-seats" (from PROJECTIONS) in the first update don't work. The field isn't updated. I have already tried with other values but nothing.

I am sure that the procedure is executetd because the second update still works. It marks the cart entry as "CONFIRMED".
I don't have any trigger on this field.

My tables contains valid data (<>NULL).

I execute this procedure like this (in a BEGIN END; block):

```
CMDPLACES.VALIDER(1);
```

Thank for your reply.

Comment: This is a stored procedure. If you simply press F5, it will just compile. Are you really executing this procedure? If yes, then what is your input parameter?

Comment: Are you sure that `WHERE` clause of your first update returns any record? I would advice to add some debug output to verify that. Also as a side note: why not use straight SQL update without cursor looping?

Comment: Do you have null values in the existing data for column remaining_seats? Because `null -/+ anything` is NULL.

Comment: `UPDATE` does not throw a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception if zero rows are updated as this is not an error. If you want to check whether zero rows are updated and raise an error then you can do `IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN raise_application_error( ... ); END IF` immediately after the `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Is it `day` or `dateseance` in your first update?

```
UPDATE PROJECTION
SET remaining_seats = (remaining_seats - tabseances(i).nbrplaces)
WHERE  num_copy = tabseances(i).num_copy 
  AND dateseance = tabseances(i).dateseance
  AND time_slot = tabseances(i).time_slot 
  AND movie = tabseances(i).movie;
```

Also as *@ThorstenKettner* was mentioning, the *timestamp* data in the date , may fail while comparing, so we have `TRUNCATE` the timestamp data using `TRUNC()` [*if needed*]!
If the date column is *indexed*, beware the index will not be used by the *database* .

To handle *NO Data* in `UPDATE`, you can check `(SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0)` to identify the number of rows updated!

Comment: No, PROJECTION and PANIER are two different tables with other fild names. I handled the No Data exception and added the TRUNC() but it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, One other possibility is a `CHAR` vs `VARCHAR` field comparison. Before that, can you try a ``SELECT` with what ever `WHERE` condition and values you have, to make sure the data exists? Also, can you please describe your tables for column definitions?

Answer (score 0):

Your first update compares days. What data type are these? In case you deal with DATETIME, make sure to compare without the time part if any. Use TRUNC to achieve this.

```
AND TRUNC(day) = TRUNC(tabseances(i).dateseance)
```